# How to apply NavLink activeStyles to its child components

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to wrap a stencil component with the NavLink is React.js.

my children components are like this

```
 <submenu-item icon-name="archive">{t('sometext')}</submenu-item>
```

And then I wrapped this component with NavLink as below.

```
const NavbarItems = ({ items = [] }) => {
return items.map(({ children, to }) => (
<NavLink
    activeStyle={{boxShadow: '0 2px 0 0 green', color: 'red'}}
    to={`${REACT_APP_PATH}/${to}`}
    style={{textDecoration: "none"}}>
    {children}
</NavLink>
 ));
};
```

With this code, the issue is that When the link is active, then box-shadow is applied and not the font colour. **Why this font colour change is not applied here?**.

Answer (score 0):

fontColor is not a property. Change your code to this

```
color: 'red'
```

This should work

Comment: Does the color change to red if you add color: 'red' inside style props?

Comment: Yes, it is there in the styled attribute.